# Install Orchard to an existing database

Tags: database, content-management-system, installation, orchardcms

In our team, we use a common database server. When running the Orchard Setup, I point the connection string to an existing Orchard Database and got this error message:

> Setup failed: The requested service 'Orchard.IWorkContextAccessor' has not been registered.   To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

The only way that can make setup successful for me is to point to an empty database. I attempted a workaround by doing so first, and then edit connection string in App_Data\Sites\Default\Settings.txt, but then I got the same error.

Comment: Anything else in your app_data?

Comment: It's very simple to reproduce: just download the source code, open in Visual Studio, build and run, and during the setup step, point to an existing database.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, also tried copying the settings.txt file which did not work. This time I copied all the contents of the App_data directory over and it worked for me. Also, this latest time I was using the latest commit from codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted cache.dat and restarted the website in IIS, this fixed it for me